# Reading a BigTiff file GDAL

Tags: python, shapefile, gdal, geotiff-tiff

Would be glad if someone helps me do this. I'm trying to convert a raster .tif file to a .shp file for some analysis. I'm using a 1.5GB data file and have installed GDAL using Conda. But if I run the code it says the following error:

> RuntimeError: This is a BigTIFF file.  BigTIFF is not supported by
>   this version of GDAL and libtiff.

What should I do to solve this error? Please explain as I'm totally new to Python environment!

```
import os
from osgeo import gdal, ogr
import sys
# this allows GDAL to throw Python Exceptions
gdal.UseExceptions()

#  get raster datasource

src_ds = gdal.Open("IND_ppp_2015_v2.tif")
print (src_ds)
```

Comment: what is your version of gdal ? By the way, it is unlikely that you will be able to store the result in a shapefile, you should try with another format (e.g. postGIS)

Comment: I'm using v2.2.2 GDAL. Is there any specific version I should try?

Comment: Your version of gdal is fine, what matyers is your libtiff version (below 4.0 doesn't support bigtiff). Please post your libtiff version (you can find it by doing gdal-config --libs).

Comment: the libtiff version im using is 4.0.9

Comment: Odd. Documentation http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html claims `When built with internal libtiff or with libtiff >= 4.0, GDAL also supports reading and writing BigTIFF files (evolution of the TIFF format to support files larger than 4 GB).`

Comment: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/9887

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! I updated the library to a newer version and it works now

Comment: Could you elaborate? Which library and how? My version of libtiff is also 4.0.9, and latest version i was able to find is 4.0.9...
http://www.simplesystems.org/libtiff/

Comment: @J.A.Cado I downloaded the package from conda's environment and then tried. Try googling conda gdal install. I think that's how it worked for me